# Erro no índice, como não existente

Tags: python

Estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro na linha 7 do código, que diz `url=to_crawl[0]` - *IndexError: list index out of range*

```
import requests

import re

to_crawl=['https://www.globo.com']

crawled=set()

header={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0'}

while True:

    url=to_crawl[0]
    try:
        req=requests.get(url, headers=header)

    except:
        to_crawl.remove(url)
        crawled.add(url)
        continue

    html=req.text
    links=re.findall(r'<a href="?\'?(https?:\/\/[^"\'>]*)', html )
    print("Crawling:", url)

    to_crawl.remove(url)
    crawled.add(url)

    for link in links:
        if link not in crawled and link not in to_crawl:
           to_crawl.append(link)
```

Comment: Você tem um *loop* infinito que não possui um `break`. Cedo ou tarde acabarão os valores em `to_crawl`, não existindo o índice 0, pois a lista estará fazia. Quando seu código deveria parar de executar?

Comment: O programa se encerraria no momento em que percorresse todo o site em busca de links, quando surgiu esse erro eu não conseguir encontrar o problema. Nesse caso eu colocaria um break ?

Comment: Então ao invés de `while True` poderia ser `while to_crawl`

Comment: Não esta dando o mesmo erro, porém o programa não esta percorrendo o site como deveria, simplesmente pula a instrução e encerra o programa, creio que seja por causa do to_crawl no while !

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu bloco **while** você está colocando o primeiro item da lista **to_crawl** para fazer a conexão, a qual está verificada dentro do bloco try/except. Quando ocorre um erro e ele entra no bloco **except** e remove a única URL que existia na lista, deixando a mesma vazia, em seguida ele passa para a próxima iteração, a qual repete o comando para atribuir o primeiro item da lista na variável **url**, mas acontece que a lista está vazia, por isso ocorre esse problema.
O que está fazendo a sua conexão cair no bloco except está no seu dicionário **header**, existe um caractere **…** na declaração do cliente, quando eu retirei para testar, a consulta foi feita com sucesso. Então você pode tirar, deixando a definição dessa linha assim:

```
header={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; ) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0'}
```

Uma possível solução para o seu bloco **except** poderia ser uma verificação para saber se a lista está vazia, e se estiver, finalizar o script, por exemplo:

```
try:
    req=requests.get(url, headers=header)
except:
    to_crawl.remove(url)
    crawled.add(url)
    if not to_crawl:
        break
    continue
```

Espero ter ajudado! :)